# How can I prove this inequality $\frac{|xy|}{2x^2+y^2}\le1 $?

Tags: inequality

How can I prove this $\frac{|xy|}{2x^2+y^2}\le1 $ ? I was thinking about considering the left term a function and maybe show that 1 is the extreme point

x,y can be any real number but not 0

Comment: Can $x,y$ be any real number? It might also be worth mentioning that $x$ and $y$ cannot both be zero at the same time.

Comment: yes , x,y can be any real  number but not 0

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$$2x^2+y^2\ge x^2+y^2\ge 2|x||y|\ge |x||y|$$

Answer (score 4):

we have  $$2x^2 + y^2 \ge 2\sqrt 2 |x||y| \Rightarrow \frac{|xy|}{2x^2 + y^2} \le \frac 1 {2\sqrt 2} < 1.$$

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. This provides a stronger statement, namely (for $x^2+y^2\neq 0$) that $\frac{|xy|}{2x^2+y^2}\le \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$, with equality iff $\sqrt{2}|x|=|y|$.

Answer (score 1):

For $x>0$ and $y>0$ or $x<0$ and $y<0$
$$\frac{xy}{2x^2+y^2}$$
$$\frac{1}{\frac{2x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}}$$
here the denominator always is grater than 1

For $x>0$ and $y<0$ or $x<0$ and $y>0$
$$\frac{-xy}{2x^2+y^2}$$
here the value always is negetive